# In Ember, is it possible to access the app directly in an acceptance test?

Tags: ember.js

I have a mixin that handles showing messages to users at various parts of the app. There are hooks in the routes can remove or show them, etc.

I'm having trouble testing this mixin directly and in an isolated manner, because I need a full functioning app, with transistions etc.

I can test it in a "normal" acceptance test, in a specific use case, but that would technically be for a separate workflow that makes use of this mixin.

I'd like to load the app in an acceptance test, and then call some methods on certain controllers (application controller in this case), if possible.

I do have access to an application instance via:

```
var application;

module('Acceptance: ApplicationMessaging', {
  beforeEach: function() {
    application = startApp();
  },

  afterEach: function() {
    Ember.run(application, 'destroy');
  }
});
```

Comment: If you need to test the mixin but in a truly isolated way you might just write a unit test w/ a dummy class that can inherit the mixin. Then you could test that object to verify certain actions/behaviors. The downside of this approach is that you can't verify the transitions and in that case I'd recommend writing a true acceptance test for at least one happy path.